# Visual Studio 2012 high CPU usage and unable to debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 3. When I open a project, VS automatically creates a process called `<myproject>.vshost.exe`, even before starting to debug.

When I start debugging and later close the debug application, most of the times the `<myproject>.vshost.exe` process closes as well. When this happens, `devenv.exe` starts taking up 3x more memory than normal and CPU goes up to 25% (on a i7 Quadcore with 8GB ram) for around 1 minute. At the end of 1 minute, a new `<myproject>.vshost.exe` opens up (even though I'm not debugging), CPU falls back down to 0 and memory drops back down as well.

Trying to start debugging whilst the CPU is at 25% and `<myproject>.vshost.exe` is not running in the background will results in the solution building but the debug does not start.

If I wait until the CPU falls back down and `<myproject>.vshost.exe` process is running again then I can start debugging normally.

This happens to me 80% of the times after closing the application I am debugging. The remaining 20% of the times when I stop debugging `<myproject>.vshost.exe` continues running in the background and I am able to start debugging again immediately after with no delay.

This also happens regardless of code changes in between debugs.

This is a new install of VS2012 U3, I've tried resetting all settings and disabled ReSharper but still no joy.

I don't want to disable vshost debugging because of the features I would lose.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before? Is this a known issue? Are there any solutions/workarounds?

**EDIT**

I changed the platform from Any CPU to x86 and it appears to work properly, but I still can't understand why I shouldn't be able to debug it as Any CPU. Even though this might be the workaround I'd still be interested in knowing whether this is a known issue and if there are other (better) solutions.

By 'working properly', I mean that when I stop debugging the vshost doesn't close, in fact it never closes, but the CPU of devenv stays at 0% and it allows me to start and stop debugging as many times as I want one right after the other.

**EDIT2**

Actually it appears that changing the platform to x86 only worked properly for a while, after about 20 rebuilds it is now doing the same as leaving it as Any CPU.

On another note, closing and opening VS makes no difference.

Comment: Is VS trying to load symbols during the slow times?  If so, it might be timing out trying to load symbols that it's never going to find, like third party assemblies.  Have you tried starting your debug build without debugger attached, then later attaching, does that have the same slow behavior?

Comment: No, this happens on a brand new C# project with nothing but an empty window form (also happens in WPF projects).

Comment: I have VS2012 U3 but can't reproduce this problem, anything interesting going by in the output window during the slow times?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, whilst VS itself doesn't freeze (I can access controls in VS), if I minimize it I can't maximize it until the CPU drops back down to 0%

Comment: Use a debugger.  You have one, start VS again.  Attach to the process when it burns core to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up formatting the computer again and re-installing everything from scratch. For not it appears to be working fine, let's see how long this lasts for.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several months old but I'm trying to post this answer in a few places since this is what was causing my ills: I had the Data Sources toolbox open in Visual Studio 2012. Once I closed that, it seemed to eliminate the lengthy delays when switching windows. You may also want to close Server Manager if you don't need it open.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old Post but, I think I need to share my solution for everyone.
and this is my first post so, please improve the answer if I miss something.
I have the same issue with Visual Studio 2012, When I try to build or debug it will use CPU up to 100%.
So, I try below steps to reduce the CPU usage while debugging:

- Please close unnecessary opened file.
- Hide unnecessary debugging panels like: breakpoints, auto, local, output, find  symbol result, etc.
- If still use high CPU then try to hide call stack panel.
- Remove unnecessary breakpoints.